# “HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools” Entry Does Not Show Up in Registry

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio

I am trying to make changes to the registry entry at

```
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools"
```

But the SharePointTools does not show up in my registry. I do have Sharepoint 2010 installed on my machine. Would there be any settings changes or any reason it does not show up?

Thank you.

Comment: I've noticed that you haven't accepted any answers to your questions yet. Please accept answers that helped you or post your own resolution and accept that if community answers did not help you. This helps future visitors of the site quickly see if an answer was valid.

Answer (score 1):

From WROX P2P "Professional SharePoint 2010 Development" (page 43):

> Last, because SharePoint builds on many layers below it, such as Windows Communication Framework (WCF), you may want to enable advanced debugging in your VS environment. To do this, go into the registry editor, find `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\SharePointTools]`, and change the `DWORD` value for `EnableDiagnostics` from 0 to 1. **If the `DWORD` value does not exist, create it as a new `DWORD` value.** When you set this value, you will see in the output window in VS all of the information that VS is getting from SharePoint via the stack trace.